# cannot install pandasql in anaconda and having proxy issue

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, pandasql

I know this is an old topic but I keep having trouble with installing pandasql in anaconda, I hope someone could help...

what I have tried:
open anaconda prompt, type pip install pandasql, then I got the below error:

"WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect = None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError... 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pandasql/"

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pandasql (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for Pandasql

I saw some postings saying that it may be proxy issue and I just want to check if my IP is blacklisted by https://pypi.org, then I go curl https://pypi.org

I got the below error:

curl: (28) Failed to connect to pypi.org port 443 after 84242 ms: Timed out

could anyone advise that what else I can do? to install pandasql in anaconda?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `conda install (package name)` instead of pip, since you’re using anaconda already

This page gives you the specific command

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandasql

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work for me...here is the error https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&ik=eecca9607c&attid=0.1&permmsgid=msg-f:1719959192097631026&th=17de85c5c125ab32&view=fimg&fur=ip&sz=s0-l75-ft&attbid=ANGjdJ_9vfqhup2Iic0UQhDtX9DaIiPA5Aw--C8LqtlVCPefwiMfFeRiBxW-nJoPsmbTvkhoLkBfDFxBO-Npse2PiHb4LyHzJah2Dp_eezpW6A2XSzPFicx0Oye1aRI&disp=emb

Comment: Why does your error point to google mail?

Comment: sorry when you click it, won't it point you to a picture?